# Difference between IE6 versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Whats the difference between version 6.00.2800 and 6.00.2900 of Internet Explorer 6?

Can anyone confirm different CSS rendering between IE6 SP1, SP2, SP3 ?

Should I browser test my pages across different Service Packs?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's no difference aside from minor security points. A quick google search yielded http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-11641.html, the inability of IE6 SP1+ to render "chromeless windows."