# Minor differences in IE6 Versions across different OS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, frames

I have a strange bug where customers fill bug reports on W2K machines in IE6, when locally testing on a WinXP System I can't see any.

I was wondering whether you know of differences in JavaScript Execution?

Sorry there is no code, since I could not reproduce this bug and the bug is somewhere in 7000+ lines. I don't mean different Versions (like in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230905/difference-between-ie6-versions)).

Comment: As IE is part of explorer which is embedded in the OS I could understand there being any differences. Could you maybe explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Thats the problem, I just have user unreliable reports. As per default JS Errors are off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any differences. What I can think of and have seen cause issues is the Windows theme, i.e. Classic or XP. In addition to your window chrome for the OS this also changes the styling of form fields inside your web pages, things like inputs, selects, textareas, scrollbars look different and take up slightly different dimensions which can throw out your layout if its laid out to work with exact dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out there was an issue with cached files. So there is no difference!